# c++ compiler that supports all c++11 concurrency features?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++11, shared-memory

I try to learn writing  parallel codes with thread library of c++11 so first of all I need a compiler that support this library my question is that what compiler can support all concurrency features of c++11?

**Caution:**

**this question is about concurrency features of c++11 not for a compiler that best supports C++11.**

Comment: I believe VC++11 implements all library features of C++11 but it is still in [beta](https://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us)

Comment: @Prætorian VS11 beta is supported for production code, so I wouldn't worry too much about the 'beta'

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the cited question. For some reason both answers missed the fact that OP is asking for a compiler that supports C++11 concurrency, not for a compiler that best supports C++11. But that doesn't make the question the same as that other one.

Comment: @Tamás Szelei: I attempted to answer the posters questions with several links to different compilers. Since there are multiple compilers that support different part so of the thread library I was hoping he would see one he can use in there (since there is several different features).

Comment: @Prætorian Somebody who still misses `<cfenv>` and most of the new floating point functions cannot really claim to implement all library features, anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet is too take a look at the [support matrix](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) from the Apache wiki as mentioned on [C++11 Compiler: Closest to the standard and how close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232878/c11-compiler-closest-to-the-standard-and-how-close). From there you will be able to see what compiler bet suits your needs.

**Visual Studio**

As mentioned from [C++11 Features in Visual C++ 11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) "In VC11, we intend to completely support the C++11 Standard Library, modulo not-yet-implemented compiler features."

**GCC**

[C++0x/C++11 Support in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

**Clang**

[C++98 and C++11 Support in Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

Comment: "In VC11, we intend to completely support the C++11 Standard Library, modulo not-yet-implemented compiler features" - Thats not true anymore for the November '12 compiler version.

Comment: @smerlin what isn't true in that?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx `...does not yet come with an updated standard library to use the features (such as a std::vector initializer_list constructor).`

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at this?
[C++0x/C++11 Support in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

Comment: I installed gcc but I don't know what is its version how can I find it?

Comment: use the --version flag (`g++ --version`)

Comment: Although I don't know how this answers the question since the table shows that g++ has almost all C++11 **except** the concurrency features.

Comment: @ehsan: Use the command "g++ --version", you will then see something such as "g++ (GCC) 4.6.1". Which I do. Also, please see my answer.

Comment: @eshan:  `gcc -v` should give you the version.