# Is C++11 widely supported?

Tags: c++, c++11

For someone who wants his C++ code to be portable across the different C++ compilers, is it time to start using C++11, or is it going to be a while before the new standard is supported by all of the major compilers (VC, GCC, CLang, Intel)?

In other words, what's the status of C++11 support among the major compilers?

Comment: clang and g++ have very good support. The point is that, more often than not, the infrastructure powering industries usually does not count bleeding-edge compilers among its guns.

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport

Comment: Please see the C++11 tag wiki (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b11/info)

Comment: Scott Meyer's has [a page with links too each compilers support page](http://www.aristeia.com/C++11/C++11FeatureAvailability.htm).

Comment: @JesseGood thanks, I didn't know that! Very useful, you could post as an answer.

Comment: @Mat Thanks for the link, but the FAQ and the linked page refer to the standard as C++0x, which makes me think they might be out-of-date.

Comment: It's pretty well supported by *the latest versions* of the major compilers. You also have to consider if you want to support older versions of these compilers.

Comment: Stability of the new features is also a concern - especially with the long turn-around time for VC++ bug fixes.

Comment: This is also a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7232878/46642. And, just in case, "but the answers on that one are outdated" is not a valid reason for *yet another* dupe (there are more). Post a bounty if you're interested on an updated answer. If you think that doesn't work well... well, then you just made it clear why this is "too localized".

Comment: It was interesting, too bad it has been closed. Instead of systematically closing fresher questions, there should be a way to deal with outdated, less relevant ones...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clang (updated regularly):

> http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

GCC 4.5 to 4.7 (updated regularly):

> http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Visual C++ 10 and 11 (a bit old, but newest I've found):

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Recent versions of all major compilers have support for *some* C++11 features. But no compiler has complete support yet, and if you want your code to be portable, you likely also have to consider that not everyone are using the latest versions of their compiler.

So the answer is "it depends".

There are a number of features supported by all major compilers. (`auto`, rvalue refs and lambdas, for example, are widely available).

There are also a lot of features which are available on some, but not all, compilers.

The links posted by @Kos should give you a good idea of where each compiler is at.

Whether you can/should start using C++11 yet is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the mentioned websites: A comparison of different compilers  containing the exact version from which on the compilers support a c++11 feature is found here:

http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport

Listed Compilers:

HP aCC,
EDG eccp, 
GCC,
Intel C++,
MSVC,
IBM XLC++,
Sun/ Oracle C++,
C++ Builder 2009/10,
Digital Mars C++,
Clang

Comment: I wonder if the page is still being maintained. It does not mention recent Visual Studio 2013 additions.